# HTML5 Canvas - awesome charts error - when used inside php - base64 output

Tags: html, canvas, charts, base64

First thanks for the awesome charts - they are simple and i am trying them out for a friends website.

A brief abt the site -it is a stock market related website trying to show a index from Bombay Stock Exchange in detail. Doing it for a friend basically for free.

The site is in wordpress and use wp exec php for inserting php into posts etc. I am trying to insert the chart html code inside php - since I get a variable data through php from a url and on the fly i define it into a csv - field like - echo $mycsvfile[49][0];  which out puts a value from 49th row 0 coloum.

So if the php ends the temp values are lost so basicallt what i have to do is - get both the java script and also html div into the php.

what i tried first was to get the div only into php to sse the default output - but the output is coming as - base64 code - ie numericals etc. I dont know how to output that into image  and embed into the page - inside php.

The link being - http://www.shariah50.net/live-stock-price-quotes-shariah-index-bse/

Trying to display two images- inside php and another one pure html as u had given.

pls guide

1. how to output that into php and get an image
2. how to code the javascript into php - since i need to pass variables into the javascript.

Two ideas i had - dont know how good they are - is it ok to convert the canvas element into a jpeg or png, and secondly - can we convert the in page javascript into a php query...

Waiting for ur reply - tried to find a solution for it but couldnt online ...

What code i am using is basically below -

---

echo '            '; 
echo '   '; 
echo '                    Your web-browser does not support the HTML 5 canvas element.'; 
echo '                '; 
echo '            ';

?>

.chart_container{ text-align: center; width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0px 25px; float: right; }

```
        <div class="chart_container">
            <canvas id="chartCanvas11" width="400px" height="400px" float="right";>
                Your web-browser does not support the HTML 5 canvas element.
            </canvas>
        </div>



      <script type="application/javascript">
     var chart11 = new AwesomeChart('chartCanvas11');
        chart11.chartType = "horizontal bars";
        chart11.title = "Charts";
        chart11.data = [-12.62,13.3,10.06,4.27,1.96,0.78];
        chart11.labels = ['IE','Firefox','Chrome','Safari','Opera','Other'];
       chart11.colors = ['#006CFF', '#FF6600', '#34A038', '#945D59', '#93BBF4', '#F493B8'];
        chart11.randomColors = true;
        chart11.draw();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the basic flow is:
Create an Image element that has the base64 image string as src value. Example: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...`

I don't really understand your question and how it is related to html5, but "putting javascript into php code" is the same as "putting html into php code".